# Loading images Faster in Webpage

Tags: jquery, html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the web application when i click on a link that should load an image from server, it is taking too much time since the images are sized approxmately 3MB - 5 MB, we are unable to reduce the size because of the image resolution problem.

There is one solution to put height and width, but we are unable to put height and width for the image. How can we resolve it?

I am loading the images from server into div like

```html
<div>
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Srtm_ramp2.world.21600x10800.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. But WHY is it not possible to specify a height and width?

Comment: You should use lower resolution images as you would a thumbnail, and only show the full resolution image if the user either clicks on it or mouses over it... whatever your application requires. This way you wont be loading lots of huge files the user isn't even interested in.

Comment: Even if you resize the output of the image on the screen, you're still loading the full image size.

Comment: I will suggest you to compress images.

Comment: @Fergoso thanks for replying , the reason not to use height and width is the resolution is not good. we are unable to read the content in the images.

Comment: @Hayes thanks for replying, we have to show the full resolution image at a time, as the user reads the content in the image and crops what ever content he needs on the image.

Comment: Looks like your concern is the text in your images?

Comment: yeah, image consists of content, like news, the user crops the content on the image what ever he requires.

Comment: Your best option would be to redo the images by stamping and re-typing them in the smaller version.

Comment: @GaryHayes If the image is supposed to be showed on mouseover, how would it not be loaded? you can't show a image which isn't loaded.

Comment: If you cannot reduce quality, then I suggest you slice images up into several smaller images and piece together as you would a puzzle. Fireworks is a good program for doing this.

Comment: "There is one solution to put height and width, but we are unable to put height and width for the image. ", i am not able to understand how come an image load faster by putting height an width?

Comment: What about preloading images??

Comment: A really good article describing different image preloading techniques. https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: Despite other improvements given in other answers, if all images are of the same resolution and your goal is only a better responsiveness but the number of images is not too large, you can join all images in a single one, display it in a container with fixed dimensions and overflow:hidden and play with margins to move it inside to position it accordingly with the actual image you want to en each moment.

Comment: Do you have an example page, we could try out?  It's a tad hard to visualize your problem.  I'd go with preloading and php to put in dimensions.  What do you do with mobile users?  Are you dynamically changing your graphics file name "enu_20150522_1.jpg"?   The answers that already exist are pretty good.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat its a webapplication and iam changing the image dynamically.

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more detail? What application are you using? How slow is the process? Is preloading an option?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to explore for managing large images:

Try to bring down file size (3-5MB is too high IMHO):

- Remove all metadata
- Reduce resolution/pixel-density
- Reduce height/width of the image
- Use JPEG compression
- Use GZIP compression on your server

You can also explore:

- Use a CDN to serve images (to allow parallel loading)
- Use services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)/[IMGIX](http://www.imgix.com/) which allow you to
  dynamically select the image size you want

Comment: Offcourse loading this much size images definitly takes much time, I Go with JPEG Compression, That brings my Images to 60% Less of its actual size..

Answer (score 7):

> How it works
> We’re going to remove the images from the HTML, then put them back in using jQuery. Simple as that.
> This will allow the images to load after all of your other content has finished

> > PLUS, there’s an important added benefit: search-engines measure your page-load speed by what’s in your HTML, not what jQuery loads after the fact. That means that when Google measures your site’s loading speed, the page speed result will look significantly better.
> > This is how to do it:

> > > Firstly:
> > > Remove all of the big images from your HTML (my images just happened to be in an unordered list):
> > > Remove all of the big images from your HTML
> > > [image]

> Secondly:
> Add a jQuery snippet that will add them back into the HTML, after everything else on the page has loaded:

```js
$(window).load(function(){ // This runs when the window has loaded
    var img = $("").attr('src', 'YourImagePath/img.jpg').load(function() {
        $("#a1").append(img);
        // When the image has loaded, stick it in a div
    });
    var img2 = $("").attr('src', 'YourImagePath/img2.jpg').load(function() {
        $("#a2").append(img2);
    });
});
```

Done :D

Answer (score 5):

Use HTTP Cache Header for your images .  Once loaded images will not reload before cache expiration as defined by HTTP Cache Header.

Comment: .png, .jpg, and .gif images are already compressed when saved in the file.  Using gZip will not help.

Answer (score 5):

Try loading images when `document` loads by utilizing `background-image` property of a container element ; set container element `display:none` . This should cache images in browser , eliminating need for additional requests to server for images at time of actual `click` - image already loaded into `document` , cached in browser before first `click` on "link" or `button`. On `click` of "link", or `button` , toggle `display` property of container element having `id` same as `className` of clicked `button` between `"block"` , `"none"` ; displaying , not displaying image , at each `click` of "link" `button` .

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[class^=img]");

Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons)
.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  document.getElementById(elem.className)
  .style.display = "none";
  elem.onclick = function(e) {
    var img = document.getElementById(elem.className);
    img.style.display = (img.style.display === "none") ? "block" : "none";
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 1800px;
  height: 1600px;
}
div[id^="img"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div[id="img-1"] {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1800/1600/cats);
}
div[id="img-2"] {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1800/1600/technics);
}
```

```html
<button class="img-1">image 1</button>
<button class="img-2">image 2</button>
<div id="img-1">
</div>
<div id="img-2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to compress the size of your images as big images took time to upload.
2. Use jpg/jpeg files or zip files to upload.

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't reduce the image file size then load the images dynamically :

https://github.com/pazguille/aload

At least the page will be responsive to user input while the images are downloading.

Answer (score 2):

I believe others have given you some good answers on how to optimize the image for downloading.  My answer focuses on other aspects which can have a significant effect on web pages.

Preload the dimensions of your image with php with server.

```
<?php
list($w,$h) = getimagesize("enu_20150522_1.jpg");
echo('<img src="http://myserver.com/enu_20150522_1.jpg" width='.$w.' height='.$h.'>');
?>
```

This will not improve speed, but it will allow browsers to populate rest of page while img downloads.  It will look faster.  Sometimes perception can be reality.

In addition, use CSS or Javascript, etc. to Preload your images.  I'd use Javascript.  There are lots of good sites out there on this.  Tops on Google:
[3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

If you combine both of those and compression, you may have a working solution.  But it's hard to say without a working sample.  SSR

I'd also check out:
[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
with reference to optimizing content, specifically cache.

Answer (score 2):

See Dear follow this url: [Website Performance Checker](http://tools.pingdom.com/)

paste your domain name or url and test your site, then find your image link and click on it right click save and uploaded it again. Your image file size will be auto reduced but the image quality will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a solution like google did (still does), with mobile browsing, where you basically setup a proxy, which can

- Gzip it (on the proxy)
- use other protocols  (spdy eg)

[Here](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/03/data-compression-in-chrome-beta-for.html) is the data compression google did:

Otherwise if you cant change the image, and you cant reduce the quality in any way, and if you cannot change the server, (and the suggested javascript liberays does not suffice), then it sounds like you dont have any choice. However since you only specifed it should be done in under 5 secounds (which roughly translates to a 10 mbit download for the wiki example), then either you have too many images, or the required internet speed is very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply simply using Microsoft Office Picture Manage, so then you will be able to resize your picture as document without loosing it's quality, try it!

Comment: Please provide more information.  This is more like a comment than an answer.  While your suggestion may solve the OP's problem, it is unclear how or why.  Explanation, sources, and quotes from documentation to clarify how this is an answer should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try Loading It Dynamically Using The Back Code In Your .CS File
Such As

.ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="1200" Height="300" ImageURL='<%#Eval("ThumbnailPath")%>' class="slide" /></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

.CS

```
    GallerySTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PPDB"].ConnectionString;
    GalleryCN = new SqlConnection(GallerySTR);

    string LoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM Albums";
    GalleryCN.Open();
    GalleryCMD = new SqlCommand(LoginQuery, GalleryCN);

    GalleryDA = new SqlDataAdapter(GalleryCMD);
    GalleryDS = new DataSet();
    GalleryDA.Fill(GalleryDS);
    Repeater1.DataSource = GalleryDS;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

This is my code using ASP.NET Repeater COntrol i hope this gives you an idea for the faster loading ;) always try to load it dynamically ;) Loading Images Dynamically Gives The Best Results cuz the truth is you cannot reduce the size ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Tips:**

- If images are common among several pages, you may use **CSS Image Sprite** thing, that will reduce the round trips and for faster delivery of image you may use **CDN**.
- If images are random try **async** loading of Images, this will not kill the UI/UX.
- Convert images to **png** then use them, or you may try new WebP as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your image progressive by photoshop. You should save as for web and check progressive checkbox. More details described [here](http://peteschuster.com/2013/01/saving-jpegs-for-the-web-setting-photoshop-up-for-progressive-jpegs/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce the file size significantly. As you suggested, the easiest way to do that is by reducing the image's resolution.

In a web server environment, you have two options:

1. Manually open the image in a graphics editor (e. g. Gimp), use the "Save for web" option and set the image's dimensions and quality according to your needs.
2. Set up a batch image manipulation software on your server and some regularly triggered jobs to run over all your images and scale them to a bunch of smaller resolutions for all possible device types.
3. Have your image requests run through a real-time image optimization service like [tiny.pictures](https://tiny.pictures/). They (disclaimer: or "we", respectively) get the original, huge image in real-time, scale and optimize it, and deliver it back to your visitors. You can set the dimensions you'd like as URL parameters (as was probably your first idea, though usual web servers can't do that).

The following snippet shows how you can reduce your image's width from 10800px to 400px (see width parameter), thereby reducing the file size from 5.9 MB to 6.3 kB (a **reduction of ~99.9%**). All you have to do is prepend the original image's URL.

```html
<img src="https://tiny.pictures/api/demo/?width=400&source=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Srtm_ramp2.world.21600x10800.jpg" alt="World map">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing slow loading of dynamic images recently and I did this simple trick with `jquery` and the images came a lot faster.

First create container elements to load your images into:

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Next, preload the image you want to appear on click at the start of your `JavaScript` file (if you want to preload multiple images see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476681/9272040)):

```js
const img = $("<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Srtm_ramp2.world.21600x10800.jpg'/>");
```

Finally, in your click handler, simply fill in the image into the container:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#container').html(img);
});
```